# Grouping high dimension Y-space to lower dimensions

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, feature-engineering

I have a ML problem with 300 variables to predict, Meaning I have a multi-label binary classification problem with a Y space of 300 and with about 2000 rows only.
Thus we assume that there are 2^300 permutations. However, it is not so.

Let me explain with an example.
X1,....X400 | Y1,Y2,Y3...........Y299,Y300
'healthy',..'sad'| 0,1..1,0
'unhealthy'...'sad'|1,0,....0

However when i aggregate across the rows,there are maybe about 100 combinations far less than 2^300 combinations such as this.
so Y1,Y2,Y100 => C1 OR Y33,Y44,Y291,Y299,Y300 =>C2 ... till C100
Thus, I can change it to a multi-class problem to predict these 100 classes instead.
However, there are a lot of classes with count of 1 or 2. More than 50%. Thus, this approach doesnt work so well.

Is there an **algorithmic way to still do the multi-label** but by grouping the variables in the most optimal way like from Y space to Z space with dimension 5 for example.
{Y1,Y10,Y222,Y232}=> Z1 can be grouped together
{Y2...} => Z2 can be grouped together
Thus,we can predict on the Z space instead. At this point, I am not sure whether the Y variables need to be exclusive to one Z group or not.

But I am open to all suggestions at this moment ..

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You may find this resource helpful : https://xang1234.github.io/multi-label/

> One possibility is to cluster similar labels together so that they are
> processed together by the multilabel classification algorithms.
> Community detection methods such as the Louvain algorithm allow us to
> cluster the label graph. This is implemented in the
> NetworkXLabelGraphClusterer with the parameter methods = louvain.

A resource for splitting your data into (hopefully) balanced train,val,test sets (not so easy because you are in a multi label setting) : http://scikit.ml/stratification.html

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I have tried the graph algo to reduce it to 10 Y dimensions. The metrics are better now. However, have to run through with the stakeholders if this is Ok with them.